# localtime with very old dates

Tags: c, time, timezone, localtime

I've been messing around with `time.h` and have come across the following strangeness.

```
time_t t;
struct tm loc, utc;
t = -11676066452; /* This time is mostly arbitrary. */
loc = *localtime(&t);
utc = *gmtime(&t);
printf("localtime: %s", asctime(&loc));
printf("gmtime:    %s", asctime(&utc));
```

The output is

```
 localtime: Sat Jan  1 00:00:00 1600
 gmtime:    Sat Jan  1 08:12:28 1600
```

So, apparently, the local absolute offset from UTC at that time is 8 hours, 12 minutes, and 28 seconds. The chosen date is well before timezones were even established, so how is `localtime` determining this offset?

My timezone is America/Vancouver (Pacific Daylight Time, or a UTC offset of -7 hours, currently) and I am using glibc 2.27.

Comment: The Microsoft page for [localtime()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/localtime-localtime32-localtime64?view=vs-2019) says *Return a pointer to the structure result, or `NULL` if the date passed to the function is: Before midnight, January 1, 1970* and similarly for `gmtime()`. Presumably your implementation did not, because you can't dereference a `NULL` pointer, but the date range validity may be relevant. It's unreasonable to expect a library function to know about the history of DLS around the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply observing the offset for the LMT ([Local Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time)) entry for `America/Vancouver` from the [IANA TZ Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

```
# Zone    NAME               STDOFF    RULES    FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone      America/Vancouver  -8:12:28  -        LMT     1884
                             -8:00     Vanc     P%sT    1987
                             -8:00     Canada   P%sT
```

Source here: https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/2020a/northamerica#L2134

You can read more about LMT (and lots more) in the [`theory`](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/theory.html) file in the tz database.

Comment: I had just noticed this and was going to leave an answer about it! Actually, I had noticed that the 8h12m28s offset was related to the longitude of Vancouver. Good to know that it's called LMT, though. I suppose all timezones in the IANA TZ database have a LMT default if you go back far enough.

Comment: Thanks for the resources, too.